# div background display bug seemingly unrelated to properties using css grid area with 3 z-index levels

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a full website using only CSS Grid for layout. The goal is pixel perfect responsive [goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UpaD.png)

Current iteration is [all done except that background bug on the call to action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I29Ek.png)

As you can see the bottom border of the portfolio button behaves incorrectly. All borders sides should be 2px in size. The bottom it is too large, despite the 3 divs involved being set with the exact same size minus margin on the sides, which is intended. On any page size, only the bottom border is behaving improperly.

The intended solution to put a gradient border to a call to action is to make divs on 3 z-index levels: one background level 1 that is a gradient the full size of the box with border, one level 2 actual box which is the same size -2px to create a 2px background from the border, and one level 3 div that actually holds txt content.

I tried setting a specific size, playing with padding and font line height, but all it does is increase the size of the black area inside the button and push the bug further to the bottom without influencing its size.

I have no idea what's going on so I'm including all code just to be sure. The bugged button part is between ** in the CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
  grid-template-areas: 'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'vb vb vb ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho vc vc vc' 
  'vd vd vd vd vd vd lc lc lc lc lc lc ve ve ve ve ve ve ve ve' 
  'vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf' 
  'vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg' 
  'vh vh vh vh vh vh vh vh pf pf pf vi vi vi vi vi vi vi vi vi' 
  'vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj' 
  'vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj' 
  'vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj' 
  'vk vk vk vk vk vk vk vk vk tb vl vl vl vl vl vl vl vl vl vl';
}


/*txt */

#hero,
#portfolio {
  font-family: ChanticleerRoman, serif;
  color: #CD8F8F;
}


/*spacing method 2 */

#voidA {
  grid-area: va;
}

#voidB {
  grid-area: vb;
}

#voidB {
  grid-area: vc;
}

#voidD {
  grid-area: vd;
}

#voidE {
  grid-area: ve;
}

#voidF {
  grid-area: vf;
}

#voidG {
  grid-area: vg;
}

#voidH {
  grid-area: vh;
}

#voidI {
  grid-area: vi;
}

#voidJ {
  grid-area: vj;
}

#voidK {
  grid-area: vk;
}

#voidK {
  grid-area: vl;
}


/*content */

#hero {
  grid-area: ho;
  font-size: 3.875em;
}

#void2 {
  grid-row: 8 /span 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 7;
}

#languagechoice {
  grid-area: lc;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#languagechoice>div {
  padding: 12.5%;
}

#engflag,
#fraflag {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px 3px 0px 3px;
}

#eng,
#fra {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.gradient-holder {
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  z-index: 2;
}

**#portfolio {
  font-size: 2.250em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  z-index: 3;
  grid-area: pf;
}

.gradient-holder-pf {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  z-index: 2;
  grid-area: pf;
}

#portfolio-box {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  z-index: 1;
  grid-area: pf;
}

** #toblog {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-area: tb;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 39%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-prehome.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sitemap"></div>
    <b id="voidA"></b>
    <b id="voidB"></b>
    <b id="voidC"></b>
    <b id="voidD"></b>
    <b id="voidE"></b>
    <b id="voidF"></b>
    <b id="voidG"></b>
    <b id="voidH"></b>
    <b id="voidI"></b>
    <b id="voidJ"></b>
    <b id="voidK"></b>
    <b id="voidL"></b>
    <div id="hero">
      <p>Experience is born from exploration</p>
    </div>
    <div id="languagechoice">
      <div class="gradient-holder">
        <div id="eng"><img id="engflag" src="gb.png" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gradient-holder">
        <div id="fra"><img id="fraflag" src="fr.png" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-box">
      <div class="gradient-holder-pf">
        <div id="portfolio">Portfolio</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="toblog"></div>
    <aside id="Contacts-methods"></aside>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Just a note - footer tags are not allowed outside the body

Comment: That seems to be an incredibly (even over-) complex template layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#container {
  width: 100% [OR] auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
  grid-template-areas: 'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va va' 
  'vb vb vb ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho vc vc vc' 
  'vd vd vd vd vd vd lc lc lc lc lc lc ve ve ve ve ve ve ve ve' 
  'vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf vf' 
  'vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg vg' 
  'vh vh vh vh vh vh vh vh pf pf pf vi vi vi vi vi vi vi vi vi' 
  'vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj' 
  'vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj' 
  'vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj vj' 
  'vk vk vk vk vk vk vk vk vk tb vl vl vl vl vl vl vl vl vl vl';
}


/*txt */

#hero,
#portfolio {
  font-family: ChanticleerRoman, serif;
  color: #CD8F8F;
}


/*spacing method 2 */

#voidA {
  grid-area: va;
}

#voidB {
  grid-area: vb;
}

#voidB {
  grid-area: vc;
}

#voidD {
  grid-area: vd;
}

#voidE {
  grid-area: ve;
}

#voidF {
  grid-area: vf;
}

#voidG {
  grid-area: vg;
}

#voidH {
  grid-area: vh;
}

#voidI {
  grid-area: vi;
}

#voidJ {
  grid-area: vj;
}

#voidK {
  grid-area: vk;
}

#voidK {
  grid-area: vl;
}


/*content */

#hero {
  grid-area: ho;
  font-size: 3.875em;
}

#void2 {
  grid-row: 8 /span 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 7;
}

#languagechoice {
  grid-area: lc;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#languagechoice>div {
  padding: 12.5%;
}

#engflag,
#fraflag {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px 3px 0px 3px;
}

#eng,
#fra {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.gradient-holder {
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  z-index: 2;
}

**#portfolio {
  font-size: 2.250em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  z-index: 3;
  grid-area: pf;
}

.gradient-holder-pf {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  z-index: 2;
  grid-area: pf;
}

#portfolio-box {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(128, 77, 77) 0%, rgb(205, 143, 143) 80%);
  z-index: 1;
  grid-area: pf;
}

** #toblog {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-area: tb;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 39%;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-prehome.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sitemap"></div>
    <b id="voidA"></b>
    <b id="voidB"></b>
    <b id="voidC"></b>
    <b id="voidD"></b>
    <b id="voidE"></b>
    <b id="voidF"></b>
    <b id="voidG"></b>
    <b id="voidH"></b>
    <b id="voidI"></b>
    <b id="voidJ"></b>
    <b id="voidK"></b>
    <b id="voidL"></b>
    <div id="hero">
      <p>Experience is born from exploration</p>
    </div>
    <div id="languagechoice">
      <div class="gradient-holder">
        <div id="eng"><img id="engflag" src="gb.png" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gradient-holder">
        <div id="fra"><img id="fraflag" src="fr.png" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-box">
      <div class="gradient-holder-pf">
        <div id="portfolio">Portfolio</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="toblog"></div>
    <aside id="Contacts-methods"></aside>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No effect on the button. It did improve my layout but not the problem at hand.